# Random Banner/Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, javascript-objects

```html
<!bx slider header script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>



<script src="{{ get_public_template_url("custom/page/SpjainMarch2016-theme/fitvids.js") }}"></script>
<script src="{{ get_public_template_url("custom/page/SpjainMarch2016-theme/bxslider.js") }}"></script>
<script src="{{ get_public_template_url("custom/page/SpjainMarch2016-theme/fancybox.js") }}"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
       helpers : {
        media: true
    },
    width       : 800,
    height      : 450,
    aspectRatio : true,
    scrolling : 'auto',
    preload   : true,
    openEffect    : 'elastic',
    closeEffect    : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
  mode: 'fade',
   auto: true,
  controls: true,
    randomStart: false,
  autoStart: true,
        pager: true,
        adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
        autoControlsCombine: false,
     autoControlsSelector: null,
        preloadImages: 'visible',
    onSlideAfter: function(){
      console.log("next");
      if($('.menu-head.up-slide c').hasClass('active')){
          console.log("next1");
          $("#bx-pager li.first d").addClass('active');
   }
  }
});

</script>


</head>


<body>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";


.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

/** THEME


.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -30px;
 width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
 min-height: 50px;
 background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: .85em;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
 display: inline-block;
 *zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
 background: #666;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 display: block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 outline: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
 background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
 left: 10px;
 background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
 right: 10px;
 background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
 background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -16px;
 outline: 0;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
 display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
 background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
 background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
 text-align: left;
 width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
 right: 0;
 width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #666\9;
 background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
 width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 display: block;
 font-size: .85em;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!bx slider compound code>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>{% if widget.slide1.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.slide1.src }}" width="{{ widget.slide1.width }}" height="{{ widget.slide1.height }}" alt="{{ widget.slide1.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.slidercontent }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni2.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni2.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni2.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni2.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni2.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni2content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni3.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni3.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni3.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni3.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni3.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni3content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni4.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni4.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni4.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni4.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni4.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni4content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni5.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni5.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni5.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni5.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni5.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni5content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni6.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni6.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni6.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni6.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni6.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni6content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni7.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni7.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni7.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni7.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni7.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni7content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni8.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni8.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni8.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni8.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni8.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni8content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni9.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni9.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni9.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni9.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni9.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni9content }}</div>
    </li>    
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni10.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni10.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni10.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni10.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni10.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni10content }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.alumni11.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.alumni11.src }}" width="{{ widget.alumni11.width }}" height="{{ widget.alumni11.height }}" alt="{{ widget.alumni11.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.alumni11content }}</div>
    </li>
   <li>
{% if widget.slide2.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.slide2.src }}" width="{{ widget.slide2.width }}" height="{{ widget.slide2.height }}" alt="{{ widget.slide2.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.slidecontent2 }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
{% if widget.slide3.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.slide3.src }}" width="{{ widget.slide3.width }}" height="{{ widget.slide3.height }}" alt="{{ widget.slide3.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.slidecontent3 }}</div>
    </li>
  <li>
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#slideModal_V" href="#slideModal_V">
  {% if widget.slide4.src %}
    <img src="{{ widget.slide4.src }}" width="{{ widget.slide4.width }}" height="{{ widget.slide4.height }}" alt="{{ widget.slide4.alt }}">
{% endif %}</a>
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.slidecontent4 }}</div>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="bx-pager" class="side-menu">
  <li class="menu-head first"><a data-slide-index="0" href="">{{ widget.slidername }}</a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="1" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="2" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="3" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="4" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="5" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="6" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="7" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="8" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="9" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head up-slide"><a data-slide-index="10" href=""></a></li>
  <li class="menu-head"><a data-slide-index="11" href="">{{ widget.slidename2 }}</a></li>
  <li class="menu-head"><a data-slide-index="12" href="">{{ widget.slidename3 }}</a></li>
  <li class="menu-head"><a data-slide-index="13" href="">{{ widget.slidename4 }}</a></li>
</ul>










</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to edit a banner with 13 images. With every refresh, random image needs to show with a random order(all 13).

I am using bx-slider. Here is the homepage [www.spjain.org](http://www.spjain.org)

I have made the random image at refresh but the order is still same.

Any clue whats wrong?

Update: Already using randomStart: true,

Comment: Could you add some relevant code in your question?

Comment: @Gael Edited the question. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You are using bxSlider with option randomStart: true. In their document, it mentioned

> if random start, set the **startSlide** setting to random number

And there is no option to shuffle play all your other slides.

http://bxslider.com/docs/jquery.bxslider.html

Solution is instead of using javascript, you may want to random the sequence of your image ul list in your server code.

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
  <li> ...
  ... </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it make sense.

Comment: So should I add random number here - if(slider.settings.randomStart) slider.settings.startSlide = Math.floor(Math.random() * slider.children.length);

Comment: @John, no this script is what jquery.bxslider.js will activate if you add randomStart: false in your js option. I am refering to your server code loop for your bxslider ul list: If you random the li sequence loop in your server then everytime someone access your page the whole list will be shuffled.

Comment: If I use below shuffle/random filter(server code) the banner shows blank.                
  <ul class="bxslider">
  <li>{% if widget.slide1|shuffle %}
    <img src="{{ widget.slide1.src }}" width="{{ widget.slide1.width }}" height="{{ widget.slide1.height }}" alt="{{ widget.slide1.alt }}">
{% endif %}
    <div class="slide-caption">{{ widget.slidercontent }}</div>
    </li>

Comment: Since you use HubSpot, This should be what you are looking for https://community.hubspot.com/t5/COS-Design-Support/creating-array-from-dynamically-generated-widgets/td-p/6736 "in the HubL docs, there is a filter you can apply to for loops that is supposed to choose one random item from the sequence."